# Button opening page twice

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I have a simple form that looks like this:

```
<form action = '../../uploadGI/index.php' method = 'post' target = '_blank'>
... (inputs)
<button class='btn actionbtn closebtn' onClick = 'this.form.submit()' ... >Submit</button>
</form>
```

The forms sends a number of parameters to a new page where the user can upload a document (or scan it), the parameters are related to the type of doc, the table and table record it refers to in the db.

When I leave target = "_blank" out the form works as intended. But with target _blank the button opens the page ... twice. What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: the default action for a button input in a form is to submit the form. No need for the onclick handler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default action for a button input in a form is to submit the form. No need for the `onClick` attribute/handler. Just remove the `onClick`

```
<button class='btn actionbtn closebtn' ... >Submit</button>
```